# Which of these MySQL query approach is faster?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Which of these query would be faster?

1) Complicated query with subqueries

2) Simple query without subqueries but leave the extra processing work to application

I am deciding on which approach to take. I do not have real code to test against at the moment. Can those with more experience provide the answer?

Comment: Why the negative point? As I have explained, I have no code to benchmark against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the rows in the table and the sub queries you are using. Check the manual for query optimizing.

visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question was too vague to have specific answers. A link to improve my knowledge will be useful.